# Add basic auth for /admin path prefix

Tags: traefik

So I am trying to add basic auth to an applications, but only for /admin/ and /admin/.*.

I am using docker(-compose) with traefik labels. So far I have the fallowing:

```
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.port=8080
  - traefik.docker.network=proxy
  - traefik.app_admin.frontend.rule=Host:app.test;Path:/admin
  - traefik.app_admin.frontend.auth.basic=dev:password
  - traefik.app_frontend.frontend.rule=Host:app.test
```

What I want to achieve (and what I expected from the above):

An (un)authenticated user should be able to visit `app.test`. When the user navigates to `app.test/admin`, `app.test/admin/`, `app.test/admin/#/` or `app.test/admin/not/existing/path`. It should prompt(require) the basic auth creds.

I am not sure if am using the correct rules. It a little confusing (there is Path, PathPrefix and these can be used with or without `*` prefix).

The one thing that I didn't expected is going to a non-existing path like `app.test/admin/foobar/` returns a `404`-code instead of a prompting for credentials first.

Also is there a way to combine the labels and also require basic auth for all requests containing (starting with) `app.test/api/`.

edit:

I got it working with:

```
  - traefik.app_admin.frontend.rule=Host:app.test;PathPrefix:/admin
  - traefik.app_admin.frontend.auth.basic=dev:$$2y$$05$$3Zmx7gYh6mBIIm8O9HTR2uDkoYoRbTMfZpKup5NhmioKrU1YKgmqC
  - traefik.app_api.frontend.rule=Host:app.test;PathPrefix:/api
  - traefik.app_api.frontend.auth.basic=dev:$$2y$$05$$3Zmx7gYh6mBIIm8O9HTR2uDkoYoRbTMfZpKup5NhmioKrU1YKgmqC
  - traefik.app_frontend.frontend.rule=Host:app.test
```

(username: dev with password: password)

Still wondering if there is a more compact way of doing this. I might just use traefik.toml instead.